# How can I change the default wallpaper for new users?

Tags: gnome, 18.04, desktop-background

I found some old questions about this, yet not for 18.04.

We're deploying desktops via PXE/Preseed installations, and I'd like to change the default wallpaper. I found how to change the login screen wallpaper, but not yet how to change the default wallpaper for new users.

Any hint about this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default wallpaper in Ubuntu 18.04 is **warty-final-ubuntu.png**, and the most easy approach to change it would be to convert (if necessary) your wallpaper to `png` format, rename it to warty-final-ubuntu.png, then rename the original default wallpaper and copy your wallpaper to the default location.

```
sudo mv /usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png /usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu-old.png  
sudo cp /<path-to-your-wallpaper>/warty-final-ubuntu.png /usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png
```

Comment: This works, indeed, but it's more a hack than a setting. After some searches, I could not find any other way, so I'll accept this answer. I tried with `[org/gnome/desktop/background]
picture-uri='file:///usr/share/mycompany/company-wallpaper.png'` in /etc/dconf/db.ibus.01-mycompany.settings then `dconf update` but with no success : new users still get the Ubuntu's default wallpaper..

Comment: @JeanCoiron I'd rather call it a workaround (the original background image still exists and each user can select it if he wants) ... changing the "hard-coded" default settings (somewhere "hidden" in the system) would be more a hack. The dconf method doesn't work, because every user can change the background individually - once you create a new user, he starts with the default wallpaper, which in Ubuntu 18.04 has the name warty-final-ubuntu.png. Anyway, I'm glad that I could help you to achieve what you wanted. :)

Answer (score 4):

Posting as it took me some time to find a solution for **Ubuntu 20.04**, even though this is an old question, it might help others looking for this.

This is where I found the method: https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/dconf-custom-defaults.html.en

What I tried and didn't work:
I tried to edit the schemas folder directly (for people new to Ubuntu like me, the folder I'm referring to is found at `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/`). The configuration file that I needed to edit was `org.gnome.desktop.background.gschema.xml` , yet for some reason, that wouldn't be applied to the new user, plus it is likely bad practice to edit these configuration files directly.

I then followed gnome.org 's guide and created a file here:

```
sudo nano /etc/dconf/db/local.d/01-background
```

Then add the following:

```
# dconf path
[org/gnome/desktop/background]

# dconf key names and their corresponding values
picture-uri='file:///usr/share/backgrounds/your-own-wallpaper-here.jpg'
```

Make sure that your wallpaper is located at `/usr/share/backgrounds/` and that you've edited either `focal-wallpapers.xml` or `ubuntu-wallpapers.xml` found at `/usr/share/gnome-background-properties/` to include your wallpaper image (there are other posts that explain how to do this).

Lastly update dconf by running:

```
sudo dconf update
```

I would recommend rebooting, then creating a new user to test whether it's working. I hope this helps, it worked for me, let me know if you have better solutions or slightly improvements to this method.

Comment: This also works on almalinux, fedora, any distro with gnome... I use to deploy this on uni. Thanks!

Comment: You don't necessarily need to edit the existing XML files in /usr/share/gnome-background-properties. You can also add a new one; I am using <companyname>-wallpapers.xml. That can make things easier when automating deployment of such a setup.

Comment: In Ubuntu 22.04, the settings in 01-background will be ignored because they are overridden in /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/10_ubuntu-settings.gschema.override . Create another schema override file with a higher number, then recompile the schema. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1253238/how-do-i-change-default-settings-of-ubuntu for details.

Answer (score 0):

The question is about Ubuntu 18.04, which is a bit dated. In Ubuntu 22.04, a few things have changed.

The settings in /etc/dconf/db/local.d/01-background will be ignored because they are overridden in the schema, specifically in /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/10_ubuntu-settings.gschema.override

To fix that, you have to add another, higher-numbered override file and recompile the schema. The process is described here: [How do I change default settings Of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1253238/how-do-i-change-default-settings-of-ubuntu)

- Create a file named /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/20_my-settings.gschema.override. The content should be the same as described in the 01-background. You can also use 10_ubuntu-settings.gschema.override as a sample.
- recompile with glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/