# How do I change default settings Of Ubuntu?

Tags: settings

I want to change the default settings for Ubuntu. Such as the settings in Gnome Tweaks. And settings in Gnome Settings. And I want it to be there even if I compile the OS with Ubuntu Imager.

Comment: I mean about running OS

Comment: For List Of Settings, I Want to change Shell, Applications aka theme, And Dock Settings.

Comment: Position On Screen, Icon Size.

Comment: Please edit any relevant clarifications into the post itself. Comments are ephemeral and may be cleaned up once they're no longer needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a text file named `20_my-settings.gschema.override` with below content..

```
# My Default Settings #

[org.gnome.desktop.interface]
gtk-theme = 'Nordic-darker-standard-buttons'

[org.gnome.shell.extensions.user-theme]
name = 'Nordic-darker-standard-buttons'

[org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock]
dock-position = 'BOTTOM'
dash-max-icon-size = 64
```

Change the values as per your wish..

save the file & close..

**Note:** Since shell-theme is involved.. you need to install the extension `user-theme` and enable it..also make sure its `gschemas` are compiled..

copy the above file to `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/`

```
sudo cp 20_my-settings.gschema.override /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
```

and compile the schemas

```
sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
```

This will not change the settings if you already made different choices..

you need to reset the keys for above four choices..

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.user-theme name
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock dock-position
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock dash-max-icon-size
```

When ever you want to revert back above changes..
remove the file and compile..

```
sudo rm /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/20_my-settings.gschema.override
sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
```